# Celery concurrency configuration for long tasks

Tags: django, celery

I'm looking for the right configuration of celery to handle long tasks executed in django.

These are the keys of the case:

- the **tasks take several minutes** to complete, but the processing is done in a remote server
- **the worker procesing is minimal**: it calls a remote API, waits for the response and updates a local database based on the response
- there are **several types of tasks**, each task type is enqueued to one queue depending on its type, the **queues are dinamic**, this is they cannot be defined initially
- the worker can only execute **1 task of each type**. I assumed 1 only worker can manage all the tasks as its processing is low.

This is the configuration I have so far:

```
 - CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
 - CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 10
 - CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

The worker is started this way, it should handle any queue:

```
celery -A my_project worker --loglevel=info
```

My celery app is defined this way:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

app = Celery('my_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Answer (score 0):

eventlet can indeed be a suitable option for your queue, especially if your task is I/O bound rather than CPU bound. Eventlet is designed to efficiently handle I/O operations by using coroutines and non-blocking sockets, making it well-suited for scenarios where tasks spend a significant amount of time waiting for external resources, such as network or disk I/O.

here is the link to this config https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/main/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html